# iPhone Push Payload Info in App

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, push-notification

I'm trying to process some more information from my payload. This is how I set up push notification for iPhone and the message comes through and this is how i create my payload:

```
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
  'alert' => $message,
  'sound' => 'default',
  'link_url' => $url,
  );
```

In this is inside my app.

```
// WHEN a push notification comes in
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]){
        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
                if (alert["message"] as? NSString) != nil {
                    //Do stuff
                    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                    // redirect to section
                    var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewBookings")
                    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                }
            } else if (aps["alert"] as? NSString) != nil {
                self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                // redirect to section
                var initialViewController2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewBookings")
                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController2
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }
    }
```

But now i need to read link_url so my app can redirect to different sections or recommend an external link. (its not always an url)
I tried: let my_url = aps["link_url"] as? NSDictionary and then describe as string, but i get nothing.

Comment: is your aps["link_url"] a dictionary or a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the $message and $url objects are defined. If they are strings then the following should work:

```
if let my_url = aps["link_url"] as? String {
    print(my_url)
}
```

From your code it looks like your object looks like the following:

```
{ "aps" : {
    "alert" : {
        "message" : "some message"
    },
    "sound" : "default",
    "link_url" : "www.example.com"
    }
}
```